# Copy a file with linked object data

Tags: linked-data, scene, freestyle

I am making several renders of a scene, with each shot needing a different camera, pose, and Freestyle settings. I want to setup each shot and their settings separately. Normally, I would make different Scenes in the same file with Link Object Data. However, unlike other render settings, some parameters of Freestyle that I need to change affect all Scenes in a file. If I change a parameter in a Line Style such as the displacement value on a geometry modifier, it changes in all Scenes in the file. I can change Line Set settings per scene, but I need both.

Is there a way to make a whole new file but that still has Linked Object Data the same as if I had made a new Scene?

Comment: Did you try making a single-user copy of Line Style settings in second scene which is with linked copies ?

Comment: Ah, you're correct, that does work. I didn't realize that was an option. I can do that instead for now, but am still curious about the original question.

Comment: You can still use the same file with different scenes but and make single user of object only (not object data) that should keep mesh data linked but modifiers independent in the same file.